# Force to keep some variable always in cache memory

Tags: python, caching

I want to keep a variable always in the cache memory, knowing that it will be accessed in the very near future. Is there any good way to do that in Python?

Comment: You should read about "scope of variables". Your question is not very specific. Variables doesn't disappear with time. Can you explain what you have in mind with "in the very near future" ?

Comment: maybe it's more the result of a function you would like to cache ?

Comment: Yeah, but most of the processor uses some sort of "cache replacement policy" to remove less important variables from the cache memory (and possibly store it to main memory). In my case, I want to make sure the target variable will never 
be removed from the cache memory @jona

Comment: Then, you should read this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53780267/an-equivalent-to-java-volatile-in-python